# V-model doesn't update on checkbox list change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of checkboxes that are rendered with a `v-for` on a component. When checked, the checkboxes fill up an array with currently selected checkboxes. The problem comes when one or more of the checked checkboxes is removed -  the `v-model` still counts the removed checkbox. How do I update the `v-model` as my array updates? I tried force re-rendering the whole component which solves the problem but it's not the solution I need.

```
  <div v-for="player in players" :key="player.id">
  <input
    v-model="selectedPlayers"
    :value="player.id"
    type="checkbox"
    :id="player.id"
  />
  <label :for="player.id">
    {{ player.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-checkbox-forked-r0nxk?file=/src/App.vue)

Problem

[image]

Desired outcome

[image]

Comment: You could use an `active` property of your player object and bind that to the checkbox. Then just use something like `players.filters(x => x.active)` when you wanna know which players are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V-model won't remove data when the component is no longer rendered, you need to do that explicitly.

You could filter selectedPlayers from the @click handler so that it only includes ids that are in the new variable.

```
this.selectedPlayers = this.selectedPlayers.filter(
  id => players2.find(
    player => player.id === id
  )
)
```

Comment: Ideally I wanted to try out some magic with the `v-model` but I think I'll settle for this one. Thank you for posting

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand, you have this `player2` array, that you need to compare against. Whatever is there in the `players2` array needs to be there in the `selectedPlayers` array. To do this just use the use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array function to iterate over the `players2` array to return only the `ids` of the players and then store them in the selected players array which being a reactive property will automatically patch the `DOM`. **There's absolutely no need to re-render the component.**

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedPlayers: [],
      players: [
        {name: "Arnold",id: "1"},
        {name: "Rambo",id: 2},
        {name: "Terminator",id: 3},
        {name: "Titan",id: 4},
        {name: "Odin",id: 5},
      ],
      players2: [
        {name: "Titan",id: 4},
        {name: "Odin",id: 5},
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      this.players = this.players2;
      this.selectedPlayers = this.players2.map(p => p.id);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  If you check all checkboxes and press the button, the array still contains all elements
  <div v-for="player in players" :key="player.id">
    <input v-model="selectedPlayers" :key="players.length" :value="player.id" type="checkbox" :id="player.id" />
    <label :for="player.id">
        {{ player.name }}
      </label>
  </div>
  {{ selectedPlayers }}
  <button @click="clicked">Press me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I for example select only 1,2 and 3 and then press the button -> instead of having an empty array I still have 4,5 selected.

Comment: My point is that no matter how I change players - lets say I have selected 1,2 and 3 and If I delete 1 then I want to have the `selectedPlayers` only containing `[2,3]`

Comment: It doesn't work because it sets `selectedPlayers` to all of the ids from `players2`.

The code doesn't take into account the current contents of selectedPlayers at all.